# Confusing regarding sub domains of main specializations EE?

Tags: power, embedded, electrical

I want to apply for masters program in Hungary in EE

As shown  attached snapshot, there are listed 3 secondary specializations:

1. Smart city
2. Smart systems integration
3. Optical Communication

I know that subject number 3 (Optical Communication) is secondary specialization of Main specialization (Multimedia Systems and Services)

**But i am confused regarding the remaining two secondary specializations(smart city and smart systems integration), regarding to which main specialization (Electric power systems or embedded systems) they both belong/refer to?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the secondary specializations "belong" with any particular main specialization. It's more like a matrix, where each secondary specialization provides focus for any of the main specializations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the first complete paragraph of the snapshot says "Any main specialization can be combined with any secondary specialization." That seems to support what Dave Tweed said in his comment. Systems integration and optical communication are important aspects of many engineering specializations. "Smart City" likely refers to EE applied to the infrastructure of the modern urban environment. All of the main specializations listed would be applicable in that context.